# Memory leak with Core Graphics cocoa

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, memory-leaks

I can't understand what is leaking in this code. I get these 2 leaks:

[image]

I don't know how to give you more information than directly adding the code here:

```
    float value = [[dict objectForKey:@"value"] floatValue];
    UIColor *color = (UIColor*)[dict objectForKey:@"color"];
    NSString *type = [dict objectForKey:@"type"];

    CAShapeLayer *circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    circle.path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, LABELSIZE, LABELSIZE), nil);
    circle.fillColor = color.CGColor;
    circle.contentsScale = 2.0;

    CATextLayer *text = [CATextLayer layer];
    text.contentsScale = 2.0;
    text.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%%",(int)value];
    text.frame = CGRectMake(0, LABELSIZE/2 - LABELFONTSIZE/2 -1.0, LABELSIZE, LABELFONTSIZE);
    text.fontSize = 10;
    text.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;
    text.foregroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.6].CGColor;
    text.font = (__bridge CFTypeRef)([UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Medium" size:LABELFONTSIZE]);

    [circle addSublayer:text];

    if([type isEqualToString:@"IN"]){
        circle.position = CGPointMake(0, self.layer.frame.size.height / 2 - LABELSIZE/2);
    }else{
        circle.position = CGPointMake(self.layer.frame.size.width - LABELSIZE, self.layer.frame.size.height / 2 - LABELSIZE/2);
    }

    [self.labelsLayer addSublayer:circle];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your leak errors are due to

```
    circle.path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, LABELSIZE, LABELSIZE), nil);
```

As you know, [CGXxx and CFXxx are not dealt with ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029), and you need to manually release the memory. So **release the memory you created above**.

EDIT: (As commented by Rob)

> You have to call `CGPathRelease()`. For every Core Graphics method you
>   call with "Create" or "Copy" in the name, you have to call the
>   appropriate Core Graphics `CGXXXRelease` method manually (or, in some
>   cases, you can transfer ownership to ARC).

Comment: I that row I assign the path directly  to circle.path. How can I release it though?

Comment: Have I to release the entire CAShapeLayer circle after     [self.labelsLayer addSublayer:circle]; ?

Comment: Two ways: 1.break it into multilines. 2.use autorelease.

Comment: Yes think. But I always used `[... release]`. Lets have a try and check once more if leak still exists.\

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to avoid leaking the memory:

Use CFAutorelease function (only available in iOS 7+ and Mac OS X 10.9+)

```
circle.path = CFAutorelease(CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, LABELSIZE, LABELSIZE), nil));
```

Create explicit variable and release it after assigning:

```
CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, LABELSIZE, LABELSIZE), nil);
circle.path = path;
CGPathRelease(path);`
```